# What does this regex expression do?

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking after fixing a bug and there I find this expression:-

```
 directoryPath = Regex.Replace(directoryPath, "[^\\w\\.@-]", "");
```

but as a result of the expression all the high ascii characters in directory path are messed up, I am not good at regex and dont know about it but for now I have to fix the issue .

Can someone please explain me what this regular expression does?

Answer (score 3):

It replaces anything that is **NOT**

1. `word character` OR
2. `.` (dot) OR
3. `@`       OR
4. `-` (dash)

   with ***nothing***.

INPUT

```
    var directoryPath = @"C.@-(:\abc123/\def.foo";
```

OUTPUT

```
    C.@-abc123def.foo
```

Modified code to replace with `space` and corresponding output

```
    var directoryPath = @"  @.-abcd efghi(^-^)/\:jklmNO@.-PQRSTUVW   XYZ0123456789@.-";

    Console.WriteLine(directoryPath);

   //note change here
   //second argument to Replace function is chanted from "" to " "

    directoryPath = Regex.Replace(directoryPath, "[^\\w\\.@-]", " ");

    Console.WriteLine(directoryPath);
```

Output:

```
  @.-abcd efghi(^-^)/\:jklmNO@.-PQRSTUVW   XYZ0123456789@.-
  @.-abcd efghi  -     jklmNO@.-PQRSTUVW   XYZ0123456789@.-
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are having encoding issues. For example, `Regex` could have treated your string as ASCII when it really was stored as UTF-8.

Comment: wrong. it's not utf issue. it just because \\w doesn't contain chars he expected. i bet because locale specified wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be removing the first character from `directoryPath` that is not a word character (digits, letters, underscores), period, @ symbol or hyphen.

I've just tried it with `C:\Scratch\Filename.txt`, and it leaves me with `CScratchFilename.txt`.

Comment: @Andy, why does it mess up the high ascii characters?

Comment: @Ranjeet: because Andy doesn't know what is \w. which actually means "word character". so [^\\w] equals to "non-word characters"

Comment: It's removing all characters that is not a word character (digit, letter, underscore), period, @ symbol or hyphen.  Can you elaborate on what it should be doing?

Comment: @zerkms - ah, I always get that mixed up!  I think it's \s I was thinking of.